# Does the change in eye color (melanin concentration) affect the iris pattern?

Tags: human-biology, vision, human-eye

In cases of acquired heterochromia, is there a quantifiable change in the iris pattern; the clefts , furrows, etc.
If yes, what changes are observed?
And if no, are there any diseases or acquired conditions that cause a change in iris patterns?